# background-size css property doesn't work well with android WebView

Tags: android, css, android-webview

I'm using a WebView in my android app (using android 2.2 SDK) to display a html page using this css :

```
body{
background-image: url(.....);
background-size: cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

My problem is there's still a little white bar on the right of the view that I want to get rid of. How can I do that? (it works well on android 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a trick to do it:

```
webview.setScrollBarStyle(GONE);
```

That doesn't remove the scrollbar but it removes the white bar behind. If someone knows a better/cleaner way to do that please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have a better solution:

In the Layout use the XML attribute android:scrollbars="none".

Example:

```
<WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
```